# video streaming camera for kanban board

Tags: camera, agile, kanban

We are using kanban in our sdlc. There is a board put up which tracks all the tickets.

We need to use a video camera for the board.

Has any one used a zoomable ip video camera for this purpose before?

Answer (score 1):

I seem to recall Carsten Jakobsen of Systematic mention during his talk at Agile2011 that they use something like what you describe.  Systematic used Lean software engineering practices to help them achieve CMMI level 5.  There's nothing specific in it, but the [slide deck from that talk is available online](http://submit2011.agilealliance.org/files/session_pdfs/Scaling_Agile_to_the_Enterprise_with_Lean_v1_13mbp_forUploadToSite.pdf) (PDF).  Maybe you could reach out to him for more information?

Comment: I will be trying to use a lens to make the focus sharper. Thanks for response though.